# A letter isn't showing up even though it should

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I was assigned to make a combination where it would only show certain letters of the registered person's name. The way it should be is that the first and last letter, then the 4th one in the name,
e.g: Registered user's name is Teszt Elek, so it should be Tkz.
But for me it isn't showing the k.  aka the last letter. If you need more of the code, just ask.

```
var ls = szulnev.charAt(0);
var ny = szulnev.charAt(3);
var us = szulnev.charAt(-1);
var lsnyus = ls + ny + us ;
```

Comment: a) you're showing the fourth letter in the middle, not in the end b) `charAt` doesn't support indexing from the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the last character wrong:

You can achieve this using different ways but with different performance,

1. **Using bracket notation:**

var str = "Test";
  var last = szulnev[szulnev.length - 1];

But it's not recommended to use brackets.

2. **charAt[index]:**

var lastLetter = szulnev.charAt(szulnev.length - 1)

This is readable and fastest among others. It is most recommended way.

3. **substring:**

szulnev.substring(szulnev.length - 1);

4. **slice:**

szulnev.slice(-1);

It's slightly faster than substring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `charAt()` can take a negative number. You can use `szulnev.charAt(szulnev.length - 1)` see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)